# Facebook with OpenID Selector

Tags: facebook, oauth

I work with the OpenID Selector.

every thing it's ok but when click on the Facebook nothing happens.

i work with the fb module this is work fine but with the OpenID Selector just it's just select the facebook icon.

and another issues when a user login to my web site and need to log out it's still login with the service he used to login to my site.

and this issues on your site when i log in to this site use google and log out from this site i still login with the google and another service.